# Test DB with TestNG not rolling back

Tags: java, mysql, spring, testng, spring-test

I am trying to do some basic automated testing with a DB and TestNG and it isn't working. First run succeeds as I expect, 2nd one doesn't because the first one never rolled back. I have looked at several places for examples and it seems to be correct. Anyone know what I am missing

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

code:

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = AutomatedTest.Context.class)
public class RollbackTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {


  @Test
  @Rollback
  @Transactional
  public void testThing() throws Exception {

    Class<? extends RollbackTest> c = this.getClass();
    String path = String.format("/%s.sql", c.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/"));
    super.executeSqlScript(path, false);
  }

  @Configuration
  @PropertySource("db.properties")
  static class Context {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${datasource.url}") String url,
        @Value("${datasource.username}") String user,
        @Value("${datasource.password}") String pass,
        @Value("${datasource.driver-class-name}") String driver) throws PropertyVetoException {
      ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
      ds.setUser(user);
      ds.setPassword(pass);
      ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
      ds.setDriverClass(driver);
      return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public Connection connection(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
      Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();
      System.out.println("Connection is " + c);
      return c;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager txMan(DataSource ds) {
      return new DataSourceTransactionManager(ds);
    }
  }
}
```

sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA FOO;

CREATE TABLE FOO.BAZ (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO FOO.BAZ (name) values('christian');
```

error:

CREATE SCHEMA FOO

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [automated/RollbackTest.sql]: CREATE SCHEMA FOO; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can't create database 'FOO'; database exists
```

Comment: The `@Bean` method that returns a `Connection` looks very suspect. What are you doing that for?

Comment: For executing an SQL script before or after a test method, you should ideally look into Spring's `@Sql` annotation.

Comment: @SamBrannen I am returning that connection because a previous iteration of code was using it - I will remove it and see what happens. I will also look at the `@Sql` syntax

Comment: @SamBrannen I did as you suggested: the `@Sql` annotation does exactly what I was trying to do in code so that alone is worth some points! I also removed the connection and it nows seems to work. Why don't you turn your advice into an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I'll post those tips as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Bean` method that returns a `Connection` looks very suspect. So I'd recommend you delete that.

For executing an SQL script *before* or *after* a test method, you should ideally look into Spring's `@Sql` annotation.

Also, you can safely delete the `@Rollback` and `@Transactional` declarations on your test method.

- `@Rollback` is the default behavior.
- `@Transactional` is already declared on AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)